# Визуальный редактор интерфейсов для wxPerl

Tags: perl

Желательно на ubuntu. А то есть желание создать парочку программ с графическом интерфейсом, но нет желания наугад расставлять координаты кнопок и тому подобное. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: хотел рекомендовать, но он кажется для python и C++ или perl тоже?

Comment: @sercxjo, "At the moment it can generate Python, C++, Perl, Lisp and XRC (wxWidgets' XML resources) code."